# How to add Diagnostic Setting to existing Azure Kubernetes using ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-monitoring

I am working on Azure ARM Templates. I created an Azure Kuberentes Cluster using ARM Templates. Now, I am trying to enable monitoring by adding Diagnostic Setting to it using ARM Templates. For that I went with this following [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template)  where the Diagnostic Setting is added to an VM in which log setting is not mentioned. But, here I am trying to add setting to an existing AKS cluster. Could anyone suggest me that How to add setting to an existing AKS cluster?

Answer (score 0):

AKS is a managed service, it's not supported to create extensions to the existing nodes. For more details, see the issue [Can I use custom VM extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-use-custom-vm-extensions).